# Trying to center naviation bar

Tags: html, css, navigation, center

I am having problems trying to center the navigation bar on my web page.  I tried creating a wrapper div to center it, but it doesn't seem to work.  The only thing that works in that div are changing the left margin.  Here is the HTML:

```css
body {
  background: #bf5c71 url('body-bg.jpg');
}
.clearfix:after {
  display: inline-block;
  clear: both;
  align-content: center;
}
/*----- Menu Outline -----*/

.menu-wrap {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.00);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.00);
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
}
.menu li {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic';
}
.menu a {
  transition: all linear 0.15s;
  color: #FF283B;
}
.menu li:hover > a,
.menu .current-item > a {
  color: #F5F5F5;
}
.menu .arrow {
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 0%;
}
/*----- Top Level -----*/

.menu > ul > li {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.menu > ul > li > a {
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.00);
}
.menu > ul > li:hover > a,
.menu > ul > .current-item > a {
  background: F5F5F5;
}
/*----- Bottom Level -----*/

.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}
.sub-menu {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3px 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity linear 0.15s;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
  background: 0;
}
.sub-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.sub-menu li a {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.sub-menu li a:hover,
.sub-menu .current-item a {
  background: #FF283B;
}
img {
  border: thin solid #FF283B;
  margin-left: 5%;
}
h3 {
  margin-top: 3%;
  font-size: 24px;
}
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="menu-wrap">
    <nav class="menu">
      <ul class="clearfix">
        <li>
          <div align="center"><a href="index.html">Home</a></a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div align="center"><a href="#">Projects <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a href="iap.html">Image Adaptation</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="sonic.html">Sonic Memory</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="documentary.html">Documentary Video</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div align="center"><a href="resume.html">Resume</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div align="center"><a href="about.html">About</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div align="center"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

The only thing I can seem to do is just shift the bar left using margin-left.

Website: [tylerbr.com](http://www.tylerbr.com)

Comment: You can add text-align:center to content div, if you don't want to set explicite width...

Answer (score 1):

This is enough:

```
  .content {
    text-align: center;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your menu a width and change the display to "block"

Here is the style you need to change

```
.menu-wrap {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) inset;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 880px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a good idea to give a 100% width to the navbar. And the text-align center on the menu should do the trick.

```
 .menu-wrap {
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.00);
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.00);
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0px auto;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .menu {
        width: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is they style margin: 0 auto;  take a look at this sample code and you will get it.

```
<style>
.wrapper{
    width:100%;
    height: 30px;
    background: black;
}
.centered_div{
    width: 200px;
    background: red;
    margin:0 auto;
}
</style>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="centered_div">
        test
    </div>
</div>
```